# Mudar cor do menu do NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android

Mudar cor do menu do NavigationDrawer , aquele que voce puxa uma gaveta e vem o menu [image: ![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc4js.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```
    android:background="#000" --> cor de fundo
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:itemTextColor="your color" --> cor dos itens do seu drawer
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
```

em codificação seria assim

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private Text itemdrawer;
mDrawerLayout.setBackgroundResource(// sua cor aqui dentro);
itemdrawer.setBackgroundResource(// sua cor aqui dentro);
```

**Nota :** seria bem interessante voce postar sempre códigos e não só imagens... se for pra postar um dos 2 o ideal mesmo é código pois as vezes o erro é de programação ...

Answer (score 1):

Você quer dizer do menu inteiro ou só dessa imagem que fica na parte superior?

Para mudar a cor de onde fica as opções do `NavigationDrawer` (onde está na cor branca atualmente) você pode ir no `.xml` e definir a cor do background dele:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#000000" (aqui será a cor do background)
        app:menu="@menu/menu" (aqui o menu onde ficará as opções)
        app:headerLayout="@layout/main_header"/> (aqui o layout que fica na parte superior)
```

Caso quiser mudar a cor do layout superior você deve ir no `main_header` (ou o nome que tenha dado, é o layout que o `app:headerLayout` recebe) e modificar ele como você queira, pode mudar a cor do Layout todo se quiser:

```
    main_header.xml

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="160dp"
       android:background="" (cor do main_header aqui, caso queira uma cor gradiente você deve fazer um drawable e definir ele como background, ou pode colocar uma imagem também)
       ...>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Como usar cores gradientes aqui explica: https://developer.android.com/samples/GridViewPager/res/drawable/gradient.html